# openSSL how to sign a certificate with SHA256

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, sha256

I would like to know how to use the openSSL tools to sign a certificate signing request with sha256 as the message digest.

I don't quite understand if the digest is already computed in the request, or if it is computed by the CA.

For creating the request, the tool **req** allows to specify which message digest to use, and -sha256 is an option.

However, for signing the requests, openSSL provides two tools: **ca** and **x509**.
However, none of those allow for using sha256. According to the official documentation, **ca** only supports md5, sha1 and mdc2. **x509** only supports md2, md5, sha1, mdc2.

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the documentation might be old, actually.  I believe it works, although it may or may not use the `-md` switch.  Have you tried it, yet?

According to [this thread](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/21029), sha2 support was included by default awhile ago.  So there's no reason it shouldn't work.

Indeed, [this thread](https://jamielinux.com/articles/2013/08/create-and-sign-ssl-certificates-certificate-authority/) shows a user using `-md sha256` with a `ca` command.

Also, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-openssl-certificate-signing-requests-with-your-certification-aut) seem to corroborate the the sha256 switch can be enabled in the `openssl.cnf` file as the `default_md` for the CA.

And [this thread](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Is-Sha2-supported-for-signing-certs-td26962.html) shows some issues with the `--help` documentation.

Good luck!